# Android: OneSignal how to change Notification bill icon with custom icon or app icon?

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

When notification is received the bill icon is shown instead of app icon or custom icon that i override it to be shown from code. i could to change the icon from the dashboard but i want to handle it from the code

**Intilaization**

```
    OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)// to hide dialog
            .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
            .init();
```

**Receiver class**

```
  class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler
{
    // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result)
    {
        OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
        JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
        String customKey;

        Intent intent = new Intent(Roshetta.app, SplashActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


        int requestCode = 0;

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Roshetta.app, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

            android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(Roshetta.app)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setLargeIcon(largeIcon).setContentTitle(result.notification.payload.title)
                    .setContentText(result.notification.payload.body )
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setSound(sound);


            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
             notificationManager.notify(0, noBuilder.build()); //0 = ID of notification


            if (data != null)
            {
                customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
                if (customKey != null)
                    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
            }

            if (actionType == OSNotificationAction.ActionType.ActionTaken)
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "Button pressed with id: " + result.action.actionID);


            Log.i("OneSignalExample", "ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler");
```

}

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to create a icon named `ic_stat_onesignal_default` in your `drawables` directory which will be shown instead of OneSignal's default bell icon. It is recommend to use the [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_onesignal_default) to create the correct sizes and to make sure it will look correct before trying it on your device.

Note the app icon should no longer be used as a small notification icon as in Android 5.0 Lollipop the icon's alpha will only be used. Most app icons will just be a white squire or circle in this case.

See OneSignal's documentation page below for more details.
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons

Comment: I created a node package to help with this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/onesignal-push-icon

Answer (score 11):

**You must create icons for the following sizes:**

`drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_one_signal_default.png`

`drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_one_signal_default.png`

`drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_one_signal_default.png`

`drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_one_signal_default.png`

`drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_onesignal_large_icon_default.png`

Note that the name for size drawable-xxxhdpi is different.

I recommend creating icons with *Android Asset Studio* or from *Android Studio->app->Image Asset* to be sure to have the icons for different android versions.

**If you want to have two icons type**, one for notification area and one for notification drawer you must do the following:

1.- Create the same image icon for different sizes: `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, `xxhpi` called: `ic_stat_one_signal_default`

2.- Create a different image icon for size `xxxhdpi` called: `ic_onesignal_large_icon_default`

Looks like:
[Icon - Notification area/drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHvnk.jpg)

See OneSignal's Oficial Documentation for more information. https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons

Comment: It currently needs to be `ic_stat_onesignal_default` and `ic_onesignal_large_icon_default`.