# How can i set my app icon to one signal notification using android studio 4.2.1 programatically

Tags: android, onesignal

I am develop a simple a welcome android app of one signal notification ..one signal notification shows a bell icon but i want to replace that bell icon and show that my app icon ....so please guide for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer- [Android: OneSignal how to change Notification bill icon with custom icon or app icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664164/android-onesignal-how-to-change-notification-bill-icon-with-custom-icon-or-app)

You need to create an icon named `ic_stat_onesignal_default` in your `drawable` directory which will be shown instead of OneSignal's default bell icon. It is recommended to use the Android [Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_onesignal_default) to create the correct sizes and to make sure it will look correct before trying it on your device.

Note the app icon should no longer be used as a small notification icon as in Android 5.0 Lollipop the icon's alpha will only be used. Most app icons will just be a white squire or circle in this case.

See OneSignal's documentation page below for more details. https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons

Comment: Sir when i am create that ic_stat_onesignal_default it will give me error ...in my android drawable folder this solution not working...

Comment: Create the same image icon for different sizes: mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhpi called: ic_stat_one_signal_default

Comment: what should be the extension .png or .xml

Comment: ic_stat_one_signal_default.png

Comment: not working sir any changes required for one signal side

Comment: see here https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons

Comment: can we put it in mipmap folder rather than drawable?